# My Springboot Dependency can't be found for some reason

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

So I'm using Intellij and I am connecting to the internet via a proxy server. For some reason on my regular computer connected via wireless router it all works out but this one isn't working. I tried reloading the maven project, but to no avail.

For some reason pom.xml can't find my dependencies, and that's probably why.

This is the pom.xml: [Top of pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0EGN.png)
[Bottom of pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNdXN.png)

This is the problems tab in the console: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUvcs.png)

Comment: Please, no images of code. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode for more information. Also, use code formatting tools and paste your code into the question.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.

Comment: Have you configured a proxy for Maven?  (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Comment: @JeffScottBrown which file can I configure the proxy for Maven in?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE there is no code to be shown because it's not a code issue.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you, but in which file would I need to add the code because I can't find a settings.xml and pom.xml isn't the right one either.

Comment: Just Google. https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: @Titanpointe Take a look at the link that I provided and @CrazyCoder provided after.  That document describes settings you can configure in `[home dir]/.m2/settings.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliJ's embedded Maven, **configure your proxy as per this [link]**[1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#new_project_settings).

You can **copy the default settings.xml** file from Maven install ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml to ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.

Then, **add a proxy section** to your settings file as in explained in [this guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

Also, **check with your company's infrastructure responsible that you are actually allowed to connect to Maven Central, for example at my current company we have a well-known brand firewall that, by default, blocks it**.